# Why are two temporary cells being added instead of only one?

Tags: ios, swift

I use the bellow code to add a temporary comment to a comments section. It used to work fine, but for some reason now whenever I tap the add comment button which has the bellow code, 2 cells are added.

**Why is this happening and how can i fix it?**

```
            @IBAction func AddCommentButton(_ sender: Any) {
    fetchCurrentUsersInfo() {
        self.addComment() {
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: [self.arrayOfComments.count]) as! commentTableViewCell
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: self.arrayOfComments.count-1, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.addTemporaryComment(cell: cell)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            self.addCommentTextField.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 3:

I have found that this method which is inside of the baseVC is being run every time a comment is added:

```
@objc func CommentsTapped(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Bring up the comments view and load all data into it.
    p3CommentContainer.isHidden = false
    self.commentsVC1.commentCellDelegate!.updateP3CommentSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 900))

    self.arrayOfComments.removeAll()
    self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.loadComments({
            print("compelted?")
            self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
    self.commentsVC1.commentCellDelegate!.updateP3CommentSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 180))
    self.commentsVC1.selectedMedia = self.selectedPost?.interimMedia[self.numberMedia]
    self.commentsVC1.numberMedia = self.numberMedia
}
```

I dont know why this is and I cant find a way to prevent it from running... But I think this is what is casing the duplication of comment cells

### Update:

I commented out the temporary comment code and even then the duplication occurs...

### Update 2:

I have found that when the commented code is uncommented and used my old method works correctly, when using the single query version I have made it does not. I need this version however because my backend code needs the entire data to be there in order to create a notification.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
    refrence.updateChildValues(newData)
//            refrence.updateChildValues(["UID" :  Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid])
//            refrence.updateChildValues(["Comment" :  "\(newComment!)"])
//            refrence.updateChildValues(["timeStamp" : Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `dequeueReusableCell` line. It's nonsensical anyway.

Other improvements:

- Delete `begin-/endUpdates`
- According to the naming convention name the function with starting lowercase letter (`addCommentButton`)
- Create the index path as `IndexPath` without the bridge cast
- Add the temporary comment in the data model and assign it in `cellForRowAt`

---

```
@IBAction func addCommentButton(_ sender: Any) {
    fetchCurrentUsersInfo() {
        self.addComment() {   
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.arrayOfComments.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        // self.addTemporaryComment(cell: cell)  
        self.addCommentTextField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not fix the issue, but i did find something peculiar about my issue, see update 2.

Comment: Then the cell is duplicated somewhere else. This code inserts only one cell